# Graph using Swing without external library

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics2d

How to draw (x,y) based graph (line through those points) in Java Swing?

I can not use any external library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider JPanel as your graph paper. Now using different shapes provided by java.awt you can draw different shapes such as Line, Oval, Rectangle etc. The pixels on the screen will be your coordinates of the graph paper. Its very much simple so try it :)

Comment: You may try by overriding the paint method of the JPanel class. For that your class should extend JPanel and then inside the paint method do something like this  protected void paint(Graphics g) {g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)} make sure there is @Override over the paint method which ensures that you have overrided this method

Comment: Unless adding components to the graph using layouts, a `JComponent` provides almost as much of a painting surface as can be had using a `JPanel`.

Answer (score 3):

Use java.awt.Shape
Oval, Rectangle, Polygon, Line etc. implementing the Shape interface